# Image should be responsive and should be filled on the entire screen

Tags: html, css, responsive

I have 2 div's named first and second and I have set the width and height of them as 100%

```
.first{
     width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
.second{
     width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}
```

now I would like to add an image in each div. These images should fill in the entire div.

```
<img src="someimage.png" width="100%" height="100%"/>
```

My problem is the image should not be stretched it should be filled the entire screen. I have used `img img-responsive` classes to achieve this. The image is now getting filled without stretching but when resized it is getting resized uniformly and the height of it is also getting decreased hence the image's height  is now not getting filled 100%. Is there any way to achieve width and height of an image to cover the entire screen without stretching and decreasing the height?

Comment: Not really ... You have to consider that your screen may not be someone elses. You can set the width of the image to 100%, but the constraints of the image detairmainthe height.  If you want to be more sure, you should take an image that has enough height or accepts stretching.

Comment: The best way to achieve this is using the image as background of the divs instead adding it as an image. Can you do that? or do you need it as individual tags?

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, and you should use `width: 100%` beside `min-height: 100%` but i [**recommend**](https://jsfiddle.net/jLouyfg4/1/) you to use `background-image` with `background-size: cover`

```
.first{
     width : 100%;
    height : 100%;
}

body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.first img {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}

<div class="first">
<img alt="" src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=500%C3%97500&w=500&h=500"/>
</div>
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jLouyfg4/)**

Answer (score 0):

I use imgLiquid this is a jQuery Plugin to resize images to fit in a container.

https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid

It's super easy to use and light weight.